# Duvida sobre arquivo gerado após usar npm run build com vue-cli + webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Estou estudando e desenvolvendo uma spa, e reparei que ao usar o comando `npm run build` ele gera dois arquivos `app.js` e `app.map.js` não intendi o por que desse arquivo `.map` alguem consegue me explicar o por que dele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Os arquivos .map são arquivos auxiliares de javascript e css (e agora
>   também ts) que foram minificados. Eles são chamados de SourceMaps.
>   Quando você minifica um arquivo, como o arquivo app.js, ele pega
>   milhares de linhas de código bonito e o transforma em apenas algumas
>   linhas de código feio. Espero que, quando você enviar o código para
>   produção, você esteja usando o código minificado em vez da versão
>   completa e não-minificada. Quando seu aplicativo estiver em produção e
>   tiver um erro, o sourcemap ajudará a entender seu arquivo feio e
>   permitirá que você veja a versão original do código. Se você não
>   tivesse o sourcemap, qualquer erro pareceria enigmático, na melhor das
>   hipóteses.
>
> O mesmo para arquivos CSS. Uma vez que você pega um arquivo SASS ou
>   LESS e o compila em CSS, ele não se parece mais em nada com a forma
>   original. Se você ativar os sourcemaps, poderá ver o estado original
>   do arquivo, em vez do estado modificado.
>
> Então, para responder a suas perguntas em ordem:
>
> - Para que serve? Para desreferenciar o código feio
> - Como um desenvolvedor pode usá-lo? Você o usa para depurar um aplicativo de produção. No modo de desenvolvimento, você pode usar a
>     versão completa do Vue. Em produção, você usaria a versão minificada.
> - Devo me preocupar com a criação de um arquivo js.map? Se você se preocupa com a possibilidade de depurar código de produção mais fácil,
>     então sim, você deve fazê-lo.
> - Como isso é criado? É criado no momento da criação. Existem ferramentas de construção que podem construir seu arquivo .map para
>     você, como acontece com outros arquivos.

Retirado e ajustado de:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21719713/6009128